# can't set custom file naming of bundled files in webpack 3

Tags: javascript, webpack, sass

I expect to have my bundled files with the names **index.js** and **styles.css** *(like the names of source files)* after running webpack for production. 
But I get files with names **main.js** and **main.css** instead. My webpack config seems to be set up correcty, when I set *filename* prop in both cases. And i can't understand why this is not working. What can be wrong with my config?

"webpack": "^3.1.0"

```js
const path = require('path');

// Plugins
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

// Webpack Plugins
const LoaderOptionsPlugin = require('webpack/lib/LoaderOptionsPlugin');
const NamedModulesPlugin = require('webpack/lib/NamedModulesPlugin');

// VARS
const NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV;
const DEVELOPMENT = NODE_ENV === 'development';
const PRODUCTION = NODE_ENV === 'production';

module.exports = {
 context: path.resolve(__dirname, "src"),

 entry: "./index.js",

 output: {
  path: path.resolve(__dirname, "public"),
  filename: "assets/js/[name].js"
 },

 module: {
  rules: [
   {
    test: /\.js$/,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    loader: "babel-loader"
   },
   {
    test: /\.css$/,
    use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
   },
   {
    test: /\.scss$/,
    use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
     fallback: 'style-loader',
     use: ['css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
    })
   }
  ]
 },

 plugins: [
  new NamedModulesPlugin(),
  new LoaderOptionsPlugin({
   debug: !PRODUCTION,
   cache: !PRODUCTION,
   minimize: PRODUCTION,
   options: {
    sassLoader: {
     outputStyle: PRODUCTION ? 'compressed' : 'expanded',
     precision: 10,
     sourceComments: false,
     sourceMap: PRODUCTION,
    }
   }
  }),
  new ExtractTextPlugin({
   filename: 'assets/css/[name].css',
   disable: !PRODUCTION,
  }),
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
   filename: 'index.html',
   hash: false,
   inject: 'body',
   chunksSortMode: 'dependency',
   template: './index.html',
  })
 ],

 devtool: DEVELOPMENT ? "cheap-module-eval-source-map" : "hidden-source-map",

 devServer: {
  contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, "public"),
  historyApiFallback: true,
  host: '127.0.0.1',
  port: '3000'
 }

};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to use regex `[name]`, your should provide a object as entry because webpack will use each key of this object for for the file name of output.
If you only have one entry specified as string or array, *I suppose that `main` is the default name for bundles when none is specified*.

So, to achieve what you want, you should do the following:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        "index": "./index.js",
        "styles.css": "./path/to/styles.scss" //The .css in the key to avoid .js file
    }
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "public"),
        filename: "assets/js/[name].js"
    },
    plugins: [
        //...
        new ExtractTextPlugin({
           filename: 'assets/css/[name]'
        }),
    ]
    //Rest of your config...
}
```

**BE CAREFUL:**

- *As you are using styles as entry, **remove the import/require of the styles.scss file from your index.js**. If not it will generate a extra and useless index.css file.*
- *Unfortunately, with this configuration, if you are using automatic inject of HtmlWebpackPlugin, you will get an extra script with src to your .css file in the index.html. So this solution won't work with automatic inject.*

Comment: You're right as to providing object. But if I declare in entry object keys like you've shown I end up having files **index.js, styles.js** in _assets/js_ and **index.css, styles.css** in _assets/css/_

Comment: @VelGreen Sorry, I didn't realize about that. To avoid index.css just remove the import/require of your sass file in the index.js file. About styles.js, seems to be impossible to avoid it with a custom name. Is only possible with an entry as array, but will generate main.js and main.sass. I will update my anwser with these workarounds.

Comment: @VelGreen You are welcome, see my answer now, with the .css in the key of the entry object, you won't get the extra styles.js. The problem if you are using automatic inject with htmlWebpackPlugin